# Regex not behaving as expected

Tags: python, regex

I have just started to learn(been two days) and write Python code.

Been trying to get a regex to work but to no avail. I do not get any result.

My regex looks like this `(?<=!# )device.*\b\W` and the test string is

`!# Approved : YES
!# REASON: test
!# DEVICE: TEST1TEST2
!# ACL: <Rule No>/110 and 102/120
!# SECTION: MORI
!# REQUESTER: test1x
!# MODIFIER: test1`

https://regex101.com/r/m05Coq/1

I am trying to read the device string. As you can see this works in the Regex editor but not sure why it doesnt work when I use the same in a Python app.

My Python code looks like this:

```
import re

teststr = """!# Approved : YES
!# REASON: test
!# DEVICE: TEST1TEST2
!# ACL: <Rule No>/110 and 102/120
!# SECTION: MORI
!# REQUESTER: test1x
!# MODIFIER: test1"""

def test():
    q = re.compile(r'(?<=!# )device.*\b\W', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    print(q.findall(teststr))
```

Comment: You have misplaced `)` here: `q = re.compile(r'(?<=!# )device.*\b\W'), re.MULTILINE, re.IGNORECASE`. I think it should be `q = re.compile(r'(?<=!# )device.*\b\W', re.MULTILINE| re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: bad copy paste...I fixed the code now. The result doesnt change though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you apply the flags is slightly different, in that they should be added rather than passed as multiple arguments. This method gave me the same result as the regex tester site you linked:

```
import re

teststr = """!# Approved : YES
!# REASON: test
!# DEVICE: TEST1TEST2
!# ACL: <Rule No>/110 and 102/120
!# SECTION: MORI
!# REQUESTER: test1x
!# MODIFIER: test1"""

def test():
    q = re.compile(r'(?<=!# )device.*\b\W', flags=re.IGNORECASE+re.MULTILINE)
    print(q.findall(teststr))

test()
```

Comment: Using the binary or operator `|` as mshsayem said in their comment above would give the same result as addition for these flags, since they'll never have overlapping 1's in their binary representation.

Comment: hmm...I dont get any result for this :(

Comment: That's strange, with Python 3.5 I get `['DEVICE: TEST1TEST2\n']`. I edited to include exactly the full code I'm running. I also get exactly that with your edited example above, if I add `test()` to the bottom to call the test function.